# Stopping jQuery Autocomplete when field focus is lost

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have an input field that uses Autocomplete to show a list of possible matches to text the user enters, and under that field is another input field. When the user types in text and then clicks on the next field under it the Autocomplete drop down covers that input field.

I only want to show the Autocomplete drop down if the field still has focus, and when focus is lose abort the autocomplete action.

My code is something like this.

```
var inputID = "#"+model+field;
$(inputID).autocomplete({
    source: autoURL,
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 1
});
```

Model and field are defined as function arguments.

I thought I would be able to attach an event to catch the losing of the focus and then call something like `$(inputID).abort()` to cancel autocomplete. Or I can add a focus event handler to the field below it to trigger the abort. Nothing I've tried worked, and I've looked at the code for autocomplete and can't see a way to stop it.

I'm running jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.18

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), you can call `$(inputID).autocomplete('close');` to close the autocomplete.

Comment: I tried calling `$(inputID).autocomplete('close')` when the other field received focus, but it does not stop the autocomplete ajax call. I read the documentation, and understood it to mean that it will hide the popup after it's shown. I wish to prevent it from getting to that point.

Comment: I got it working, by calling close from the open event if the source field doesn't have focus. Doesn't abort the ajax call, but still produces the result I needed.